# How to delete duplicated rows on one file based on a common field between two files in java

Tags: java, file

I have two files

1. File 1 contains 3 fields
2. File 2 contains 4 fields

The number of rows of File 1 is much smaller than that of File 2

I would like to compare between two files based on 1st field. the first field is similar to primary key, it does not repeat(no duplicates) and it will not be null. i have gone through java's diff util but it is only comparing the file diff, and not column based diff between files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at RandomAccessFiles: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 0):

Diff sounds like a fine approach. All you need to do is preprocess the files to extract the "columns" that you want to use in the diff.

Since you've not actually described the file format, it's hard to be much more specific than that. What's your column delimiter?

Comment: The file contents are delimited by pipe (|) symbol.